Likelihood of logistic GLMs using R
I am currently working on understanding how GLMs work in R, and more precisely logistic regressions. The documentation of the glm() function states:

A typical predictor has the form response ~ terms where response is the (numeric) response vector [..]. For binomial and quasibinomial families the response can also be specified as a factor (when the first level denotes failure and all others success) [...].

I tested both methods for my response variable $Y$: either coding it as zero's and one's, or counting the number of successes and failures. While both methods give me the same estimates for the coefficients of the regression as expected, the deviances (and thus, the likelihoods) obtained from the two methods differ, and I would like to know why. Below is a reproducible example where I have one explanatory variable, $X$.
set.seed(2)

beta0 = -7
beta1 = 1.1
X = round(runif(30, 0, 10))
p = (exp(beta0 + beta1 * X)) / (1 + exp(beta0 + beta1 * X))
Y <- rbinom(length(X), 1, p)

## First method
mod1 <- glm(Y ~ X, family = "binomial")

success <- table(X, Y)[, 2]
failure <- table(X, Y)[, 1]
X2 <- as.numeric(rownames(table(X, Y)))

## Second method
mod2 <- glm(cbind(success, failure) ~ X2, family = "binomial")

The first method gives me the following results:
Call:  glm(formula = Y ~ X, family = "binomial")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            X  
     -7.042        1.421  

Degrees of Freedom: 29 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
Null Deviance:      41.46 
Residual Deviance: 13.07    AIC: 17.07

And the second method gives me:
Call:  glm(formula = cbind(success, failure) ~ X2, family = "binomial")

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           X2  
     -7.042        1.421  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  8 Residual
Null Deviance:      35.91 
Residual Deviance: 7.528    AIC: 13.49

As I said, same estimates, different deviances, and so different likelihoods. For the first method, I understand that I can retrieve the log-likelihood ($LL$) obtained with the logLik() function using the following formula:
$$
LL=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(Y_i\left(\hat\beta_0 + \hat\beta_1 X_i\right)-\log\left(1 + e^{\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1 X_i}\right)\right)
$$
where $\hat\beta_0$ and $\hat\beta_1$ are the estimates. Now, I cannot manage to find what would be the formula for the log-likelihood of the second method, and why the value is not the same as with the first method (I suppose this has something to do with the fact that the number of degrees of freedom differ).
This question has been closed once because someone pointed that this question was similar, but what I need is the formula for the log-likelihood of the second method I presented, something which is not really given in the linked question.
Any help appreciated!

This already seems to be answered here.

It's not valid to compare the likelihoods in two different formulations of the same model.  In fact, it's not even valid to compare the likelihoods of the same model (with the same data) computed by two different algorithms!  The issue is that many algorithms save effort by not including additive constants, because likelihoods are only ever compared rather than being examined on an absolute basis.
